# what is the maximum number of positions of $C$ in the $x$-$y$ plane?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> Let $A=(1,2),B=(3,4)$ and let $C=(x,y)$ be a point such that
>   $(x-1)(x-3)+(y-2)(y-4)=0$. If $\operatorname{ar}(\Delta ABC)=1,$then what is the
>   maximum number of positions of $C$ in the $x$-$y$ plane?

**Solution**

$(x-1)(x-3)+(y-2)(y-4)=0\implies AC \perp BC \implies \angle ACB =90^0 \implies$ $C$ is on the circle whose diameter is $AB=2\sqrt 2$

What next??

Comment: Hint: count the solutions of $\,CA \cdot CB = 2\,$, $\,CA^2+CB^2 = AB^2\,$ first.

Comment: @dxiv:How you deduced the first condition?

Comment: I assumed that "$ar(\Delta ABC)=1$" meant the area of the (right) triangle $\triangle ABC$ is $1$.

Comment: It is more interesting to know that one of the possible C's is on the circumference of the circle with $\angle ABC = 15^0$.